# How to use multiple autoload functions for composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, autoloader

I have the custom autoloader function in `autoload-my-func.php` file.

I want to use `vendor/autoload.php` - for composer files, but only my `autoload-my-func.php` for classes with my custom namespace. `(My_Custom_Namespace)`

Comment: require_once both, job done

Comment: @delboy1978uk, I have a problem. 
When I do this way, there is an error (class not found) for composer lib (monolog).

Comment: did you try requiring them in a different order?

Comment: @delboy1978uk, I have found the problem. require_once doesn't work with dots or works another way, than I thought,  when I replaced `../autoload-my-func.php` with absolute path to `autoload-my-func.php` - code begins to work.

Comment: it does work with dots, you just got them wrong ;-) `realpath()` converts relative to absolute paths or returns false if the path is wrong. You can use `__DIR__` to get the directory of the file you are working in, or `getcwd()` to get the current working directory, which should help you in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use vendor/autoload.php - for composer files, but only my autoload-my-func.php for classes with my custom namespace. (My_Custom_Namespace)

You should use composer's auto loader for both and define your custom namespace in your composer.json file.  If you are stuck with a poorly designed legacy system, and you need something to bridge a gulf of stupidity until you can create a better solution, then you should take a look at the documentation for [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).  Specifically, the line about "if there must be multiple autoload functions, spl_autoload_register() allows for this. It effectively creates a queue of autoload functions, and runs through each of them in the order they are defined."  When you include composers autoload.php, you eventually get a few calls to spl_autoload_register(), so simply register your custom autoloader after including composer's.